# Connecting SAS with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, sas

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
proc sql;
 connect to hadoop (user="myusr1" pw="mypwd1" 
 server=hxpduped port=10000 schema=default);
create table test as
(select * from connection to hadoop 
(select * from dataset limit 100;
));
disconnect from hadoop;
quit;
```

But my code is running without any result. I can't able see the job running in job tracker as well.

Can anybody please help?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Too much brackets I'd say.
Plus comma inside the hadoop query shall be a problem too.
Try without the comma or use `%str(;)` to mask the comma from SAS SQL processor:

```
proc sql;
 connect to hadoop (user="myusr1" pw="mypwd1" 
 server=hxpduped port=10000 schema=default);
create table test as
select * from connection to hadoop 
(
select * from dataset limit 100 %str(;)
);
quit;
```

There should be automatic disconnect at the PROC SQL boundary, so you can save some typing.